# Shift N bits an entire array of chars

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Let's say I have an array of chars and I want to shift N bits to the left each byte, carrying to the left, so only the N bits of the first character would be lost.

Example: `kxmo` shifted 3 bits to the left should become `X@hx`

This is what I have currently, but it's not working as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    //shift the array with length *len* *shift* bits to the left
    int len = 4, shift = 3;
    unsigned char a[len] = "kxmo";
    unsigned char b[len]; //X@hx

    unsigned char tmp = 0, tmp2 = 0;
    for(int i = len - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        tmp = 0 | (a[i] << shift);
        b[i] = a[i];

        tmp2 = 0 | (a[i - 1] << shift);
        b[i - 1] = (a[i - 1] << shift) ^ tmp;
    }

    printf("old: %s | new: %s\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Where am I failing?

Edit:

This is what I'm getting right now: `old: kxmo | new: �xmo`

Comment: What is the question? What do you get in the debugger? What have you tried on your own?

Comment: @Olaf I get `�xmo` which is not what I'm expecting. And I have tried the code I wrote in my question.

Comment: `0 | whatever` is the same as `whatever`. How did you calculate the sample result? Does your code do the same? Hint: XOR is useless here.

Comment: @alk My question already contains what I expect from the output. It's the second sentence. I'll add what I'm currently getting.

Comment: Fair enough, sry. I somehow seem to suffer an allergic reaction to the phrase "*it is not working*" :}

Comment: I propose you draw a picture.

Comment: Why do  you start on the right side when trying to shift to the left?

Comment: @alk I'm not sure there is any difference starting from the left or from the right. Either way I'll have to carry some extra bits to the "next" byte.

Comment: Correct. However if starting from the left you wouldn't need a second array. When thinking about the issue I imagined me and a dozen beer boxes seeing me in the need to "shift" all bottles a certain amount of bottles to the left ... ;-) I'd approached this from the left.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like that (assuming 0 <= `shift` < 8):

```
#define BITS_IN_BYTE 8
for(int i = len - 1; i > 0; i--) 
{
    b[i] = a[i] << shift;
    b[i - 1] = (a[i - 1] << shift) | (a[i] >> (BITS_IN_BYTE - shift));
}
```

I didn't check it but I hope it will do what you want.

**EDIT**

OK, I checked and it does what you expect.

NOTE --> you need to set `len` to 5 and not to 4 for `'\0'`. also note that the first iteration (`b[i] = a[i] << shift;`) will be done on the `'\0'` but since its value is 0, it is OK.

Comment: Just tried it, second character of the output is not `@`, which means it's not working as expected.

Comment: @alexandernst :) it can't be that 3 characters match and only one mismatches. You have a mistake in the prediction. The value of 'x' is 0x78 if you shift left it by 3 you get 0xC0 which is not '@' that has ASCII code of 0x40. Please check it again.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Of course you are correct. My mistake. Already fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexLop. Binary value of `x` is `1111000`. Shifted 3 bits to the left that would leave us with `1000000` which is `@`. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/ASCII-Table.svg

Comment: @alexandernst You are almost correct. Pay attention that the binary value that you have is of 7 bit length. So it is actually 01111000 and shift left by 3 will become 11000000 which is not '@'

Comment: @AlexLop. oohh, Indeed! What a silly mistake! Sorry, my fault.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you again! that is what happening when coding in hurry. Fixed it :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The interesting thing is why it worked for me with `sizeof(a[i]) - shift`...

Comment: @AlexLop. Isn't that `11110000` instead of `01111000`? You're adding a 0 to the most important bit, instead of the least important.

Comment: You need to add 0 from the MSB side. For example if you have value of '1', you represent it like 00000001 and not 10000000 (which is 2^7 != 1).

Answer (score 1):

First, imagine doing it with pencil and paper. Let's say you are shifting two bytes by three bits, you start with bytes `abcdefgh`, `ijklmnop`, and you want to finish with `defghijk`, `lmnop000`.

In order to do this, you need to extract `00000ijk` from the second byte, and `OR` it into the first byte after the shift. In order to do this, you need to shift the second byte by `8-shift` to the *right*, and mask the result with `00000111` i.e. the last `shift` bits set to `1`. This mask can be constructed by shifting `1` to the left `shift+1` times, yielding `00001000`, and subtracting `1` from the result.

Here is how you can do it:

```
char b1 = 'k';
char b2 = 'x';
int shift = 3;
int carry = 0, nextCarry;

nextCarry = (b1 >> (8-shift)) & ((1<<(shift+1))-1);
b1 <<= shift;
b1 |= carry;
carry = nextCarry;
```

Now do the same with `b2`:

```
nextCarry = (b2 >> (8-shift)) & ((1<<(shift+1))-1);
b2 <<= shift;
b2 |= carry;
carry = nextCarry;
```

If you do this in a loop, you would achieve the desired result.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/0LvNQz)

Comment: I'm testing your code, but the output is not what I'm expecting. This is the output of `printf("%s", b);` -> `[�kx`. The last character is ok, but from there on, all other characters are wrong.

Comment: @alexandernst You are expecting an incorrect result. If you manually shift `"kxmo"`, which is `{6B 78 6D 6F}`, to the left by three bits, you get `{5B C3 6B 78}`, i.e. `[�kx`.

Comment: Indeed, my expected output was wrong, as @AlexLop. said. Your code outputs what it should output. Thank you.