# Shifting arrays of bytes and skipping bits

Tags: c++, arrays, bit-shift

I'm trying to make a function that would return `N` number of bits of a given memory chunk, and optionally skipping `M` bits.

Example:

```
unsigned char *data = malloc(3);
data[0] = 'A'; data[1] = 'B'; data[2] = 'C';
read(data, 8, 4);
```

would skip 12 bits and then read 8 bits from the data chunk "ABC".

"Skipping" bits means it would actually bitshift the entire array, carrying bits from the right to the left.

In this example `ABC` is

```
01000001 01000010 01000011
```

and the function would need to return

```
    0001 0100
```

This question is a follow up of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412281/shift-n-bits-an-entire-array-of-chars/)

[Minimal compilable code](http://ideone.com/Y7vQMC)

```
#include <ios>
#include <cmath>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef struct bit_data {
    byte *data;
    size_t length;
} bit_data;

/*
   Asume skip_n_bits will be 0 >= skip_n_bits <= 8
*/
bit_data *read(size_t n_bits, size_t skip_n_bits) {
    bit_data *bits = (bit_data *) malloc(sizeof(struct bit_data));

    size_t bytes_to_read = ceil(n_bits / 8.0);
    size_t bytes_to_read_with_skip = ceil(n_bits / 8.0) + ceil(skip_n_bits / 8.0);

    bits->data = (byte *) calloc(1, bytes_to_read);
    bits->length = n_bits;

    /* Hardcoded for the sake of this example*/
    byte *tmp = (byte *) malloc(3);
    tmp[0] = 'A'; tmp[1] = 'B'; tmp[2] = 'C';

    /*not working*/
    if(skip_n_bits > 0){
        unsigned char *tmp2 = (unsigned char *) calloc(1, bytes_to_read_with_skip);
        size_t i;

        for(i = bytes_to_read_with_skip - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            tmp2[i] = tmp[i] << skip_n_bits;
            tmp2[i - 1] = (tmp[i - 1] << skip_n_bits) | (tmp[i] >> (8 - skip_n_bits));
        }

        memcpy(bits->data, tmp2, bytes_to_read);
        free(tmp2);
    }else{
        memcpy(bits->data, tmp, bytes_to_read);
    }
    free(tmp);

    return bits;
}

int main(void) {
    //Reading "ABC"
    //01000001 01000010 01000011
    bit_data *res = read(8, 4);

    cout << bitset<8>(*res->data);
    cout << " -> Should be '00010100'";

    return 0;
}
```

The current code returns `00000000` instead of `00010100`.
I feel like the error is something small, but I'm missing it. Where is the problem?

Comment: It is hard to guess what you think you are accomplishing shifting a byte left 12 bits (to store in another byte) or shifting right negative 4 bits.  For any kind of generality, you should partition the number of bits you want to skip into a number of whole bytes you want to skip followed by a number (zero to seven) of additional bits you want to skip.

Comment: Also, the separate ceils in `size_t bytes_to_read_with_skip = ceil(n_bits / 8.0) + ceil(skip_n_bits / 8.0);` can make you "read" one more byte than you actually need.

Comment: @JSF oops, I messed up the question. My actual code handles `skip_n_bits > 8`. Let me update the question.

Comment: @JSF That is funny. Now it works. I think I'll delete this question and try to debug my code further as it turns out I don't even know where it's failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is tagged as C++, and indeed you're already using C++ constructs like `bitset`, however it's very C-like. The first thing to do I think would be to use more C++.

Turns out bitset is pretty flexible already. My approach would be to create one to store all the bits in our input data, and then grab a subset of that based on the number you wish to skip, and return the subset:

```
template<size_t N, size_t M, typename T = unsigned char>
std::bitset<N> read(size_t skip_n_bits, const std::array<T, M>& data)
{
    const size_t numBits = sizeof(T) * 8;

    std::bitset<N> toReturn; // initially all zeros

    // if we want to skip all bits, return all zeros
    if (M*numBits <= skip_n_bits)
        return toReturn;

    // create a bitset to store all the bits represented in our data array
    std::bitset<M*numBits> tmp;

    // set bits in tmp based on data
    // convert T into bit representations
    size_t pos = M*numBits-1;
    for (const T& element : data)
    {
        for (size_t i=0; i < numBits; ++i)
        {
            tmp.set(pos-i, (1 << (numBits - i-1)) & element);
        }
        pos -= numBits;
    }

    // grab just the bits we need
    size_t startBit = tmp.size()-skip_n_bits-1;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        toReturn[N-i-1] = tmp[startBit];
        tmp <<= 1;
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

[Full working demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0a07ee82d51ff8e)

And now we can call it like so:

```
// return 8-bit bitset, skip 12 bits
std::array<unsigned char, 3> data{{'A', 'B', 'C'}};
auto&& returned = read<8>(12, data);
std::cout << returned << std::endl;
```

Prints

> 00100100

which is precisely our input `01000001 01000010 01000011` skipping the first twelve bits (from the left towards the right), and only grabbing the next 8 available.

I'd argue this is a bit easier to read than what you've got, esp. from a C++ programmer's point of view.